# Why do we use vector subtraction to derive the cosine law?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In an exercise I was assigned, I was asked to derive the law of cosines using $ \vec c \cdot \vec c $, where $ \vec c = \vec a - \vec b $. This is a neat way of deriving it, but I don't understand why $ \vec c = \vec a - \vec b $. What makes the vector subtraction work instead of addition ? Is $ \vec c $ meant to illustrate a displacement between $ \vec b $ and $ \vec a $ ? Again, it's really cool how it works, but I don't understand why the subtraction is meaningful in this derivation.

Comment: It's tricky to answer this without the specific proof. Often, there is some kind of picture involved, where the origin is considered a vertex of a triangle with sides represented by $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$. The third side is the vector between them $\vec{a} - \vec{b}$ or $\vec{b} - \vec{a}$. This has the benefit of having the included angle in the triangle coinciding with the angle between vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. You could probably mock up a similar but different proof involving sides $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{a} + \vec{b}$, but it'll probably come out less neat.

Comment: If you make the origin one of the vertices, and $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ the two sides jutting out from it, then yes $\vec{c}$ is displacement vector representing the edge opposite the angle between $\vec{a},\vec{b}$, which is what the law of cosines is all about.

Answer (score 0):

So:

$\vec{c} \cdot \vec{c} = |\vec{c}|^2 \text{ and } (\vec{a}-\vec{b}) \cdot (\vec{a}-\vec{b}) = |\vec{a}|^2 + |\vec{b}|^2 - 2(\vec{a} \cdot\vec{b})$

and we know that $(\vec{a} \cdot\vec{b}) = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. So defining $a = |\vec{a}|$, $b = |\vec{b}|$, $c = |\vec{c}|$, we get:

$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a triangle ABC:

[image: Triangle]
<sub>[Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)</sub>

Let
$$CA\equiv\vec{b}$$
$$CB\equiv\vec{a}$$
$$AB\equiv\vec{c}$$
Then, $$\vec{c}=\vec{a}-\vec{b}$$
and
$$\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c}=(\vec{a}-\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{a}-\vec{b})=|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2-2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\cos\gamma$$
which is the cosine rule.

Now, if you instead define
$$AC\equiv\vec{b}$$
you get
$$\vec{c}=\vec{a}+\vec{b}$$
and
$$\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c}=(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{a}+\vec{b})=|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\cos(\pi-\gamma)=|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2-2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\cos\gamma$$
which is the same result.

The first convention is more convenient since the angle between the two vectors is the internal angle of the triangle.